# Method does not return the correct value (Java)

Tags: java, methods, return

```
public static char getChoice(char choice) {
    System.out.println("\nTake or stop? (t/s): ");
    choice = sc.next()
        .charAt(0);
    if (choice == 't') {
        System.out.print("Player Took");
        choice = 't';

    } else if (choice == 's') {
        System.out.println("Player didnt take");
        choice = 's';

    }
    return choice;
    //return answer;
}
```

This is the portion in the main thats calling it

```
        //Checking if players score is 21 when the game begins
    if(ptotal == 21)
    {
        System.out.print("\nPlayer wins!");
    }
    //Checking if the computers score is 21 when the game
    else if(ctotal == 21)
    {
        System.out.print("\nComputer wins!");
    }
    //Checking if both scores are 21 which would be a tie
    else if(ctotal == 21 && ptotal == 21)
    {
        System.out.print("\nTie!");
    }
    //If none above is true it will proceed to the loop
    else
    {
        //getChoice(answer);
        while(ptotal < 21 && answer == 't')//Loop conditions
        {
            getChoice(answer);
            //Prompting user if they would like to take or stop
            /*System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Take or stop? (t/s): ");
            answer = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("");*/


            //Checking if the input is 't'
            if(answer == 't')
            {
                //If true another card will be generated and added to the total value
                System.out.print("\nPlayer draws: ");
                pCard = getCard();
                showCard(pCard);
                ptotal += cardValue(pCard);

            }
            //Checking if input is 's'
            else if(answer == 's')
            {
                System.out.println("Player Stops");
            } 
        }
```

this is supposed to ask the user for a char input and then return a specific char depending on the if statement but everytime it returns it once i call it from the main it will not show those strings but it wont set choice to the right char. pls help.

Comment: If `choice` is `t` or `s`, why would you need to reassign it to the same thing? It's also impractical to pass in a char in this situation.

Comment: what should i do then because all i want this to do is get the input and then when called in the main use that input accordingly

Comment: i don't see any problem with the code here.  post the code that is calling `getChoice()` method

Comment: okay lemme just add it rn one sec

Comment: You are not catching the character that is returning from your function. You need to catch it in answer variable. Also if answer=='s' it will not enter in loop so the else if condition in loop is never reachable.

Answer (score 1):

```
//always post an MCVE
//see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char c = getChoice();
        System.out.println("returned value is "+ c);
    }

    //why pass a value choise if you read it from user ?
    public static char getChoice(/*char choice*/)
    {
        System.out.println("\nTake or stop? (t/s): ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if(choice == 't')
        {
            System.out.println("Player Took");
            // choice is already equal to `t`. This is not needed
            // choice = 't';

        }

        else if(choice == 's')
        {
            System.out.println("Player didnt take");
            // choice is already equal to `s`. This is not needed
            choice = 's';

        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```